# How to create three new chemical elements?

Tags: chemistry, universe, element

I'm trying to create a universe with 3 new chemical elements. I want them to be as realistic as possible but I'm not a chemist, so I need some help. I need to create:

**A gold coloured element**

- Three forms (liquid, gas and Solid)
- Can be used to count time with an atomic clock
- Can be used in construction

**A Black element**

- That has similar properties as carbon to create life and compatible with carbon-based life

**A white element**

- That has also similar properties as carbon to create life

As you can see, those elements would be also fundamental design choices. Their colorimetry is important.

First, I would need to know if this is feasible. If yes, I'll explore the place of those elements on the periodic table and finally go a little bit further on what could be possible with such elements in future questions.

Comment: It’s silicon, not silicium. I wouldn’t usually comment on spelling errors, but this one betrays a fundamental misunderstanding, since the -ium suffix is only applied to metals and silicon is not a metal.

Comment: Thank you, I will change that right now.

Comment: @MikeScott I wouldn't be so quick to think this is a fundamental misunderstanding. [Silicon is *silicium*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/silicon) in French, Danish, German, and Norwegian, among other tongues. Remember that not everyone here is English.

Comment: @MikeScott: The funny thing is, it is the Englishman's Sir Humphry Davy's fault. *He* proposed the name *silicium* after a failed attempt to isolate it in 1808. Yes, he believed that the yet undiscovered element was a metal. The proposed name stuck on the continent. Only the English language changed to the more logical *silicon* when the element was actually isolated and was found to be a non-metal like bor-on and carb-on.

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers with your edits.  Post another question instead.

Comment: I suggest that these new elements have, respectively, 5.75 protons, 18.2 protons, and 63 and 11/14th protons. These should give you the chemical properties that you prefer. As it is impossible for fractional electrons to exist, these will all be ionic, even with covalent bonds.

Comment: Is it absolutely vital to be an element? Could it just be a different arrangement of a blend of elements? Look at plastics. We can make hard or soft, conducting or non-conducting, every colour of the rainbow plastics. Or look at carbon. Diamonds to drill towards coal that we burn as a service to get paper made of carbon. Materials can be as diverse as they come by rearranging their structure and/or what else you mix them with. You can just tell your audience that your three element ideas are a blend of materials with a certain structure and you would probably be correct in RL.

Comment: If your willing to go all the way out the the stable island the first is possible, but why try to replace carbon with a new element instead of using an existing element?

Comment: Do realize this is equivalent to the problem of "Please add three integers with values less then 100 that do not equal any of the existing integers with values less then 100. You will need some narrativium and handwavium to solve it.

Comment: Wonda, when you say "plausible", what exactly do you mean? You've already gotten the real world "it's not possible" answer (which I would agree with). If you're looking to create a new and different periodic table (or perhaps even a nonperiodic table) of elements, you might consider leaving this question as is, think a little more about what specific problems you're trying to solve and then ask questions focused on those problems. In our Meta, we have a sandbox thread where you can post WIP queries like this so you can get help with question writing skills.

Comment: New minerals, alloys, or materials. Not elements.

Answer (score 12):

New elements are not scientifically plausible at all. There are no unfilled gaps in the periodic table, and almost no prospect of undiscovered stable elements above the current top end. So if you are going to have new elements they can have whatever properties you want, since you’re outside what can be explained by science. What you *could* have is a universe with different fundamental physical laws creating an entirely different periodic table, but then *all* your elements would be different, not just three of them.

Comment: This is indeed a problem. So it means that I have to tweak the fabric of the universe itself. Which looks like pretty much impossible. But let's assume that I can..

How far would I need to go to at least allow the first (golden) element to exist?

Comment: @Wonda, this is a "one question - one answer" community. Not a forum.

Comment: I understand, I will create another question in that case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability I'm no expert, but it seems it's theoretically possible for such elements to exist (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent_of_stability)

Comment: @Allure But the island is only expected to be relative stability — elements there will still be radioactive and decay, just with half lives potentially up to a few million years instead of fractions of a microsecond.

Comment: @Allure - it's also worth noting that such superheavy elements can't replace carbon.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create chemical elements this way. But, this is not where it has to end. Maybe you could try [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter). That entails matter that has been specifically tailored to meet your needs, and it does not consist of ordinary atoms.

Comment: In particular you'd need to replace outer electrons to get the changes in color and chemistry. Some problems: 1, no stable candidate particles are known, but making one up is less problematic than making up new elements. 2, "compatible with carbon based life" is exceptionally unlikely. 3, those new particles would be able to replace electrons in any element, not just three of them.

Answer (score -3):

Never let anyone tell you that X is impossible because of science.
Science has along history has proven, and disproven itself.

But like Mike said, the prospect of you finding one is low, not impossible. Meaning that you can keep adding protons until you find your 3 elements.

In real life we can't do it because it's energy intensive (It's too expensive to just keep testing over and over), but perhaps in your universe it just exists, due to how the planet formed.

The color, I don't think It's something you can control, or anyone will be interested in, so just hand wave it.

Comment: Where did I say it was impossible ? I say we can't just keep adding, it would be very expensive and no one has the money to do it. B is exactly my point, they aren't stable, what if we happen to find one that was ? Science will have proven itself wrong again.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t - it's also _possible_ that we find a material upon which gravity has no effect.  It's a big universe.  But it is _vanishingly improbable_ that the forces that make the superheavy elements unstable will suddenly have an exception.

Comment: @jdunlop Exactly, and since there isn't a tag asking for HardScience I choose to explain that to him, its improbable not impossible (although it must be close to it)

Comment: @jdunlop I don't want to live in a world where an element that isn't affected by gravity isn't real and undiscovered xD